# Calculate pixel position between two reference points

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls

I'm actually facing a problem I can't solve myself. So I'm asking you guys for help. Hope somebody can help me.

**The Problem:**

My task is to graphically display measured values. I do have two reference points. I created a sketch witch might explain the problem better:

[image: Measurement Scetch]

As you can see in the picture above the two lines (0.20 and 0.05) are my reference points. As you know the canvas' coordinate system is inverse. So the Point (0|0) is in the upper left corner.

What I need is one (or maybe more) formula(s) to calculate the pixel position of e.g. the Point 0.13. I had many approaches to set up a formula myself but with no luck. The points drawn in the image are variable. The height and the reference points are pretty much static.

Thanks for your help in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Given that `yMin` and `yMin` are the lower and upper bounds of the visible range of your measurement values (which might be `-0.05` and `0.3` in the picture's graph), you would calculate the y value of a position relative to the Canvas origin like this:

```
var y = 0.13;
var canvasY = canvas.ActualHeight * (1.0 - (y - yMin) / (yMax - yMin));
```